# Wifi gets connected at startup but internet won't work til I unco-/reco-nnect it manually

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

When the desktop opens, the wifi icon tells I'm connected to my home's network, but I don't get any internet access. I must ask it to unconnect and reconnect to the network for the web to be accessible.

`ping`, `nm-online`, and `firefox` are unanimous.

This problem occurs on two laptops, both with Xubuntu 15.04.

Note: The probleme doesn't occur when the laptop is started a short period after having been shut down (even if wifi wasn't connected), making the tracking work pretty hard.

If someone can explain me how this happens and how to avoid it, it would be great. Like, if one knows how to force a reconnection at a certain time of the startup.

Thanks

---

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5325]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Do both laptops have the same hardware?

Answer (score 0):

This command has a good chance to solve the issue:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

Run it, reboot and test.

Comment: You were right, it works

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work (for either laptop), I claimed victory too quickly. The fact is that the problem doesn't occur when the computer is started a short period after having been shut down (even if wifi wasn't connected).  Hence my mistake.